# dBase expression Similar to MYSQL not in

Tags: mysql, sql, dbf, visual-foxpro, dbase

Im getting ID's from a mysql phpmyadmin database and want to query the results to dbf. The results are ID's, I want to get data from dbfs which are not present in mysql using the id's

Is there a dBase DBF expression similar to MYSQL's

`WHERE DATA_ID NOT IN(1,2,3,4,5)`?

If there is what is it? If no any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Well is it Visual FoxPro or dBase? They are different products. Can you clarify exactly how you are accessing the DBFs.

If you mean is there an SQL expression that will work in Visual FoxPro, then absolutely - the exact same syntax you have in your question will work. SQL is a standard, don't forget, although different products may implement it slightly differently.

```
select * from mytable where data_id not in (1,2,4,5)
```

is fine in Visual FoxPro. As is:

```
select * from mytable where data_id not in (select id from myothertable)
```

... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

VFP has an INLIST() clause which works slightly different.  The first parameter is the column you are looking to match, the additional (up to 20 at a time I think is the limit) are the values the first column would appear within.  So;

```
WHERE DATA_ID NOT IN(1,2,3,4,5)?
```

should work as

```
WHERE NOT INLIST( DATA_ID, 1,2,3,4,5)
```